# Meaning of "不了" in "忘不了/喝不了/..."

Tags: translation, grammar, meaning, meaning-in-context, expressions

I know that `了` after a verb means a completion or termination of a certain action, such as:

> - 吃飽了
>     (I am) full.
> - 開始了
>     (It) has started.
> - 不動了
>     (It) is not moving anymore.

But what about `了` in `忘不了` and `喝不了`? Is `不了` an expression, or does each character have a specific meaning in this context? How would `忘不了` and `喝不了` be translated? (I suppose it would not be `I have not forgotten yet` and `I have not drunk yet`...)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[**了**](http://www.mdbg.net/chindict/chindict.php?page=worddict&wdrst=0&wdqb=%E4%BA%86) here is read liǎo which means:

> to finish / to achieve / variant of 瞭｜了 / to understand clearly   -*CC-CEDICT*

thus

[**不了**](http://www.mdbg.net/chindict/chindict.php?page=worddict&wdrst=0&wdqb=%E4%B8%8D%E4%BA%86)

> unable to / without end -*CC-CEDICT*

忘不了 = can't forget / unforgettable

喝不了 = can't drink / undrinkable

Answer (score 2):

“不了” in this context is pronounced "bu4liao3" and means "to be unable to".

**比如说：**

吃不了 unable to eat

忘不了 unable to forget

Comment: 了 doesn't mean unable to 不了 means unable to.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Flaudre's answer below, which included this:

吃不了 unable to eat
chi bu liao

You can add another 了(this time 'le') to mean 'any more' (or a change of state, from being able to eat to not being able to eat):

我吃不了了 = I can't eat any more. I'm full up. I've had enough.
wo chi bu liao le

了 is a great word!